# three.js remove shape-lines and make it 3d

Tags: three.js

i saw this example of three.js: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes.html
i tried to visualize a polygon (2d) and give it a height to make it 3d. Now i have two questions:

first, how can i remove these lines between the vectors?

second, i tried to give it a height, but it doesnt work. have i to write something in the ***var extrudeSettings*** ?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: For lines - set `wireframe:false` in material and for height  - `extrudeSettings.amount`